# finding wrong data that is non-existent

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website for a church and in the events section of the code i have this

```
$page_contents = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = '$page_content'");
$contents = mysql_fetch_array($page_contents)or die (mysql_error());    

echo "<Script>alert(".$contents['date'].")</script>";
```

I have 3 entries in the database and the dates are 0000-00-00, 2013-06-14 & 2013-06-19

The $page_content is the $_GET page id this comes through as events/$1/ and changes through .htacess to events.php?page=$1

when date 2013-06-14 is called the above echo script gives out 1993 and when date 2013-06-19 is called i get 1988

I have none of these years in my database or anything representing these in my code ? this has completely baffled me ????

Comment: can you post a DESC events from your database here please?

Comment: I beg you, please don't open this church up to such a great atrocity as SQL Injection -- please, please, please use `mysqli`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($contents)` produce?

Comment: What do you mean by DESC ?

Comment: Look at the raw output, not at what that output looks like wrongly interpreted through Javascript.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud While the intent of your message is good, it is misleading.  Just moving to mysqli in and of itself does not offer any level of protection against SQL injection.  You actually need to learn how to prevent against SQL injection whether using mysqli or mysql.  The suggestion to use mysqli is a good one though as mysql is deprecated in PHP.

Comment: with var_dump the date is string(10) "2013-06-14"

Comment: @nats0128 Here wants to to post a `DESCRIBE` query result for the DB table.

Comment: @MikeBrant, I didn't think you could send raw queries with `mysqli` if there was a `WHERE` clause. That was clearly my misunderstanding. It just pains me to see a **public** website that's already compromised.

Comment: i know what im doing with security as it was website hacking that got me into actual development,

Comment: @nats0128 it's a bit unfair to say that, while freely using the deprecated and non-secure `mysql_` functions...

Comment: @nats Seeing what the actual problem is I'd like to dispute that statement. :P

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You can send that same exact query he is showing via mysqli and it would have the same security vulnerability.  Most people look to leveraging prepared statements within mysqli, PDO, or other DB library that supports it so as to automagically prevent against SQL injection, but you must use parametrized prepared statements to get this protection. The mysql extension does not support prepared statements.

Comment: @Mike, thanks. Again, I thought the library just parsed the query and failed if you sent something raw with a where clause. But that makes total sense, I am a huge proponent of parameterized queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your output is not a string since you're missing the quotes in the Javascript you're outputting. It actually looks like this:

```
alert(2013-06-14)
```

Yeah, those are numbers, which are being subtracted...

Comment: Absolutely fantastic catch, just fantastic!